# break gdb when next fn is pushed onto the stack

Tags: gdb

is it possible that gdb breaks when next function is pushed onto the stack. If yes, how ? 
There could be situations when you dont know what is the next fn that would be called from current fn, for example, calling the next function using callback.

Answer (score 0):

If the inferior is stopped and you want to step into the next function call, you can just `step` until you reach it.

If you want a way to say "please `continue` but stop when the next function is called" -- well, there is no built-in way to do that in gdb.  If it's a real need, you could try to implement it in a couple of ways.

One way would be to use Python to automate the stepping.  The idea is, call `step` until the newest frame changes.

Another way would be to try to set a watchpoint on the frame pointer.  This only works if your code has frame pointers, though.

Comment: can you elaborate more on "Another way would be to try to set a watchpoint on the frame pointer. This only works if your code has frame pointers, though". In my C program, how can i have access to frame pointer ?

Comment: You have to know the architecture.  Your C program wouldn't watch the frame pointer, you would do it in gdb, like `watch $rbp`.